# React using div to create a vertical space between two React Components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two React Components one is called Right Column, the other is called Left Column. I would like to create a gap in between them using a div tag. I was wondering of how I could go about doing that because my setup in my App.js file is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import LeftColumn from './LeftColumn'; 
import RightColumn from './RightColumn'; 

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <LeftColumn style={{ padding: '0 10px' }} />
                <div style={{ padding: '0 10px' }}/>
                <RightColumn style={{ padding: '0 10px' }} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Would it be better off to using the margin style versus the padding style for the break in between the React Components? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the row as a flex container with a gap (and remove the empty div between columns).

somthing like:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

In case you want your columns to have the same width

```
.column {
  width: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `gap` property like this:

```
<div className="row" style={{ gap: "10px" }}>
 <LeftColumn style={{ padding: "0 10px" }} />
 <RightColumn style={{ padding: "0 10px" }} />
</div>
```

If you really need a `div`, you can do like this:

```
<div className="row">
 <LeftColumn style={{ padding: "0 10px" }} />
 <div style={{ width: "10px" }}/>
 <RightColumn style={{ padding: "0 10px" }} />
</div>
```